# ¿Como puedo desplegar un Editext dentro de un RadioButton en AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando añadir un editext en un radiobutton al pulsar sobre el. Ejemplo, si eres mayor de 18 años aparece un Editext para introducir la edad.

Comment: Mira a ver si hay algun atributo que sea estilo android:visible=false
Y cuando le des al radioButton te lo ponga a true

Comment: Lo ideal sería dibujar tu `EditText` en un `Layout` diferente y cuando se cumpla tu condición, pues que se cargue ese `Layout` con tu `EditText`. Y lo mejor sería que adjuntes código o semejantes.

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregar los componentes:

```
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mayor de 18 años"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEdad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

Para el checkbox y el edittext y para hacer visible u ocultar el botón crear la función:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (((CheckBox)view).isChecked()) {
            findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias =)
Me ha servido para solventar la duda